# Windows 10 How to change “New Folder” default name for folders in explorer to current date and time?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry

Every time I create new folder in windows explorer I don't need it to be named New Folder. I need current date and time as folder name. For example 20:12 10.12.2016.

And, lets say, I'm too lazy to watch at the time and change folder name manually every time I create folder.

Is there any addon/extension/widget/alternative for windows 10 explorer which handle some folder_created_event or something else and change it's name when folder is created?

Comment: I would make a new right-click "Context entry". And add a simple command there. Like a BATCH file. 1) Get the current date/time. 2) Create the folder there. I mean, this should be fairly simple, and you would not have to "hack" around. | NEW ENTRY: http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/ | BATCH timestamp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us  || Posting this as a comment, because well, the "modification of New Folder name" is the question.

Comment: That question has not been successfully answered yet. This should not be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Before you begin you must change the Windows System date format under Regional Settings in Control Panel. You cannot use / in the date format since this is an invalid character for folder names. Change the / to – in the date format. You cannot skip this step. Your date format must contain valid characters for folder names.

1. Go to registry editor using the `regedit` command.
2. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`.
3. Make a new key `New Folder`.
4. Inside this key, create another key `command`.
5. Type the following value for the key inside it (edit the `(Default)` item's data):  `cmd.exe /c md "%1/%%DATE%%"`
6. Save and exit Registry Editor.

Now, to create the folders, instead of clicking `New > Folder`, instead use the context item `New Folder`. This runs the command script defined in step 5, which creates a new folder with the current date.

You will now have a folder with default name as the current date instead of "New Folder".

Comment: Nice. I named "New Folder" "New Folder [Date_Time], and set my command to `cmd.exe /c md "%1/%%date%%_%%time:~0,2%%.%%time:~3,2%%.%%time:~6,2%%"`. This gives me time as well. My regional settings have date time set to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.mmm (and the command relies on this format when doing string data extraction)

Comment: For me this only works when right clicking on a directory. the new folder gets created inside that directory. I tried to make it work in the current directory by putting it in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` but this fails.

Comment: @Gos I just checked it and it works.

Comment: For both options I get "This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action." when trying to click the "New Folder" shortcut.